# Angular JS - Route provider not working

Tags: angularjs, routes, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

Help me with this plunk

http://plnkr.co/edit/9WSWSgp55j614tBd2qbJ?p=preview`Go to above plunk and check it out pls`

am getting blank screen when using routing but its working fine when its not

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

1. You are declaring the main app module twice - once in `app.js` and once in the controller.  The `app.js` one loads first, which adds the router as a dependency, but then in your controller you are doing this:

   `var app=angular.module("githubviewer", []);`

which redefines the githubviewer module, overwriting your previous one.  To look up a module, simply leave off the second parameter (the array of dependencies).  So change that line in your controller to be this instead:

```
var app=angular.module("githubviewer");
```

2. You have the wrong module name for the router.  The correct name is `ngRoute`:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Working plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KHc2WIRMvGBDpFOwhX?p=preview